# How to get badges for all apps on android device

Tags: android, android-launcher

I'm trying to get badges for all apps on the device (for my launcher), but I didn't find the solution. **Is it possible to get badges for all apps?** Maybe somebody knows. Thanks.

Comment: There is no platform support for home screen launcher badges until  Android 8.0.

Comment: How calculate badges, for example, LG G2 (android 4.4) for apps?

Answer (score 0):

You must get those informations  from notifications..i.e. counting how much notifications you receive from Facebook or Messenger or any other app.

Comment: I thought about it but: For example, on the device with badges Facebook app doesn't reset badges if I opened it - it happens if I tap on the tab with a badge in the app.

I know the library for SET badges - [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger), but how to GET these values I don't know :(